# wrong frame size in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, ios-simulator, nib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I having to manually set my view’s frame in viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757018/why-am-i-having-to-manually-set-my-views-frame-in-viewdidload)

I have universal app for iphone and ipad, two storyboards, if I run my app on the iphone simulator in `viewDidLoad` every frame of each element in nib is correct. But if I do it for ipad (simulator) in frame is nil, but the screen looks correct. Could you please advise me smth? Thanks.

Comment: Which frame is nil exactly? Please provide a little more detail if possible.

Comment: I now check and every iboutlet has nil frame everywhere: viewwillappear, viewdidappear, viewdidload.

Comment: essentially **viewDidLoad** is the "safest" place.  you can see this problem particularly if you're launching a live camera.

Answer (score 113):

It's a very similar question to [ios setContentOffset not working on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904205/ios-setcontentoffset-not-working-on-ipad/13904962#13904962) ... And my answer is the same as there:

"You should not initialise UI geometry-related things in `viewDidLoad`, because the geometry of your view is not set at this point and the results will be unpredictable.

... `viewWillAppear:` is the correct place to do these things, at this point the geometry is set so getting and setting geometry-related properties makes sense."

This also applies to *getting* geometry-related properties. Don't get distracted by it's behaving correctly in one circumstance and not in another... The main point is that setting/getting geometry properties too early will yield *unpredictable* results.

Your screen *looks* correct because you are seeing the results *after* `viewWillAppear:` / `viewDidAppear:`.

**update (ios6)**

When using autolayout in ios6, frames are not set until subviews have been laid out. The right place to get frame data under these conditions is in the viewController method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

This is called *after* `viewWillAppear:`. But take care - they are not always called together. For example, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called after a rotation, `viewWillAppear:` is not. `viewWillAppear:` is called every time a view becomes the visible view*, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` not necessarily (only if the views needed relaying out).

(* unless the app was backgrounded and is becoming the foreground app, then `viewWillAppear:` is not called)

Comment: I checked and in viewWillAppear it is the same. All frames are nil. I don't know how to explain it for now.

Comment: warning: "viewDidLayoutSubviews" is NOT called on auto-rotate if autolayout is not enabled. The whole of auto-layout is massively INcompatible with non-auto-layout (you actually have to change your source code. Ugh)

Comment: @Adam, I agree - autolayout is mostly not useful and horrendously incompatible with non-autolayouted ways of working. The worst thing is that it defaults to ON in Interface Builder, leading to a ton of needless questions and answers on SO. Note that this part of my answer was directed to those with the checkbox ON...

Comment: Also, as the docs state, **this method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts of the view's subviews have been adjusted**. Thus, you may have to call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` if you're relying on a particular subview's size set via AutoLayout

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out why it happened. I was using AutoLayout. When I uncheck it in the storyboard then the frames are correct.

Comment: New in ios6 ... If you are using autolayout, the frames are not set until us views are laid out ... So if you need to check/ get frames do it in -viewDidLayoutSubviews.