# UIScrollView initializes with a frame at {0, 0} but width and height of {0, 0}

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I created a view controller with a navigation bar on top, a tab bar at the bottom, and nothing but a `UIScrollView` that occupies all the remaining space in the middle. I've already created a weak, nonatomic `IBOutlet` for the scroll view on my view controller's header file. What I don't understand is how, when I print out its frame values from the owner view controller, the width and height values are zero.

This is the view controller's header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AdGalleryViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@end
```

The implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect svFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    NSLog(@"scroll view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(svFrame));
}
```

Output:

```
2013-07-05 15:36:21.447 Sulit[2733:907] scroll view frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

What is going on?

Comment: Plz check youe scrollview connected with it's delegate and IBOutlet

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: I am. I've also just connected the scroll view to the file owner as its delegate (just found out after the above comment that I hadn't done that), but still getting zeroes.

Comment: The delegate doesn't have anything to do with the frame of the scroll view, please check your constraints seted for your scroll view and check the frame value in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: It's still zero when I remove Auto Layout. :(

Comment: Delete your scroll view, add it again, and make sure you are linking it properly with the outlet.

Comment: When I remove Auto Layout from the storyboard it becomes effective for all the view controllers in it, and I'm afraid I don't I want that. Also this is beginning to feel like the problem is coming from somewhere else. I feel that the answers below should somehow suffice already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In viewDidLoad: the views are loaded from the storyboard, but do not have the "correct" dimensions yet. To set/change dimensions use viewWillAppear: instead.

Comment: If you don't use autolayout the size in `viewDidLoad` will be the exact size seted in sotryboard/xib files.

Comment: If I should do it in `viewWillAppear` how come this tutorial works though? (just look at where he's writing the code, no need to watch the whole thing) http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=vLUQz7TeE7w#t=484s

Comment: try to use different orientations (landscape vs portrait), and you will see ;)

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the frame property in `viewDidLoad is` not recommended since the view's position and dimensions are not fixed yet. You should do it in `viewWillAppear:`and you'll get non-zero values.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using auto layout in a storyboard, a good place to check the frame of your `UIScrollView` is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It is called after the storyboard has laid out the views, but before `viewDidAppear:`. I find it more reliable than `viewWillAppear:` when checking the frame of a view in a storyboard.

The methods are called in this order:

1. viewDidLoad
2. viewWillAppear:
3. viewWillLayoutSubviews
4. **viewDidLayoutSubviews**
5. viewDidAppear:

Comment: Someone posted an answer that got downvoted and is now deleted, but it worked for me--setting the frame of the `UIScrollView` in `viewDidLoad`. Would you consider that a bad idea and why?

Comment: Setting the frame of the `UIScrollView` in `viewDidLoad` may sometimes work, but it causes unpredictable results and should be avoided. Here are two SO answers that have good explanations of why `viewDidLoad` should not be used: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6758424/1367622) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064672/1367622).