# Bounds and Frame deliver Wrong Value in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, layout, storyboard

I have a label in a View Controller scene inside a root view.
I set the constraint of the height to 30 using the Pins button right below.
Everything looks pretty in the storyboard.

But when I want to get the size of the element inside my code I always get the value 21. I tried `refLabel.bounds.size.height` and `refLabel.frame.height`. I call this in the `override func viewDidLoad(){ 
super.viewDidLoad()` function of the corresponding class.

Has this something to do with the intrinsic content size?

Comment: i use Xcode 7 as a IDE

Comment: I added a button, to dynamically print the size and what a wonder it works! So why doesn't it work inside the 'viewDidLoad()'-function?

Comment: Frames can be incorrect in viewDidLoad since the subviews layout has not be performed yet. Try in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`   More information on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060002/wrong-frame-size-in-viewdidload

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
refLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
let height = refLabel.frame.size.height
print("right height is \(height)")
```