# View open in iPhone 5s and 5c ( iOS 7.1 ) like iPhone 4s screen

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a problem with my screen size in My app.

For example i build app that have a single view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:testView];
```

}

In simulator (5 /5s iOS 8.1) the app open fine :

[image: a busy cat]

In my iPhone ( 5s iOS 7.1 ) the app does't stretch for all the screen :
You can see the black color in My print screen.

[image: a busy cat]

new update: I download 7.1 simulator and the problem continues.

[image: a busy cat]

Development target in general is  -  7.0

What can be done to solve it ?

Comment: try quiting and reopening the simulator

Comment: Is it the same behaviour on devices ? if not I would not really bother

Comment: You need a 640x1136 launch image to force it to use the full screen.

Comment: in simulator its work fine , in iPhone 5s it open like iPhone 4 size.

Comment: If you are not using image catalog make sure that the name defined in the info.plist for your launch screen is the same a the name of the file. Thus `default` is not the same a `Default` on a device while it works perfectly on the simulator. Since most Mac OS X machines the file system is not case sensitive while an iOS device is.

Comment: jesse crocker , how can I change the 640x1136 launch image ?

Comment: I update the question after I download 7.1 simulator.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904205/ios-setcontentoffset-not-working-on-ipad/13904962#13904962

Comment: Mateusz , thanks for the link but it still don't work.            The guy who asked the question, there is also recorded that he was unable to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem.

I do not know if it's the perfect solution but it works on all devices and all versions.

If someone blow with such a problem has to do this :
In General --> App Icons and Launch Images --> Launch Images Source

[image: a busy cat]

press Migrate and its works (-:

I hope I was able to help those who stuck with the same problem.